# Recursive Matrix determinant function?

Tags: python, loops, python-3.x, for-loop, recursion

```
def determinant(M):
    """
    Finds the determinant of matrix M.
    """
    if dimension(M)[0]!=dimension(M)[1]:
        print("This matrix is not a square matrix and therefore cannot have a determinant!")
        return
    elif dimension(M)[0]==dimension(M)[1]:
        if dimension(M)==(2,2):
            return (M[0][0]*M[1][1])-(M[0][1]*M[1][0])
        else:
            return (M[0][0]*determinant(reduce_matrix(M,1,1))) - (M[0][1]*determinant(reduce_matrix(M,1,2))) + (M[0][2]*determinant(reduce_matrix(M,1,3)))
```

EDIT: This code here is capable of finding the determinant of 3x3 matrices, but ONLY 3x3 matrices. How can I edit this in order to find the determinant of ANY size square matrix?

Comment: What data type are you trying to return?  How do you determine the number of columns in M?  And I guess, what is M - a list of lists?

Comment: The final outcome will be a single integer which is the determinant of whatever matrix you originally start with. M is a list of lists, like [[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]]. The number of columns in M is dimension(M)[1]. Also, reduce_matrix is a pre-written function (reduce_matrix(M,i,j)) which removes row i and column j from matrix M.

Comment: Are you asking how to calculate the determinate of a matrix with an *indeterminate* number of columns?

Comment: Sort of, yes. The number of columns is dependent on the matrix you enter.

Comment: Can you use [numpy](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/)?   http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.linalg.det.html

Comment: Unfortunately I cannot import anything.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use list comprehensions to apply an expression by an input list like so:

```
[n ** 2 for n in [1, 2, 3]] == [1, 4, 9]
```

I assume you'd like to accumulate the results, in which case you can use the `sum` function.

```
sum([1, 2, 3]) == 6
```

By applying both you end up with an expression like this:

```
sum([((-1) ** i) * (M[0][i] * determinant(reduce_matrix(M, 1, i + 1))) for i in range(0, dimension(M)[1])])
```

Note that `range` excludes the last element.

Also be cautious of operator precedence:

```
-1 ** 2 != (-1) ** 2
```